# What is the type of the data structure that can hold an array of functions in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to create an array that can hold an array of functions. I am getting a compile error doing the following

```
func newMethod() {

}
var funcs: Any[] = []
funcs += newMethod // Compile error "Could not find overload for += ..."
```

Comment: The current version of SWIFT is known to be incomplete, so you may just have arrived at a corner case they haven't handled yet.  I personally expect the entire array system in SWIFT to be redesigned before it is officially released.

Comment: So currently there is no way?

Comment: try `var funcs: Array<()->()> = []`

Comment: Looking at the answers in the other question, I personally would prefer either the `(() -> ())[]` or the `(Void -> Void)[]` syntax for the array type. The first is clean, but maybe unclear, the second is nicely explicit.

Comment: The "type" of a function is the argument list followed by the return type. So (Void -> Void) if your functions don't have params or return anything.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
func newMethod() {

}

var funcs: Any[] = []
var method : () -> (Void) = newMethod;
funcs += method;
```

The `var method : ()` creates a new variable method with the type `() -> (Void)`, the type of `newMethod`. You can then add this to the array.

**You can also add functions with variadic parameters:**

```
func variadicMethod(numbers: Int...) -> (Int){
    //do something and return an Int
}]



var variadicMethod : (Int...) -> (Int) = variadicMethodForAdding
funcs += variadicMethod
```

Comment: you are calling `newMethod()` and put the result (`void`) into `method`

Comment: Sorry about that. I believe fixed it.